# External display for Surface Pro 7 stuck in 640 x 480 resolution?

Tags: external-display, displayport, microsoft-surface-pro

Just got this new system setup

- **Surface Pro 7** (running Windows 10)
- MS docking station (mini DP port)
- Dell U2414H display (DP in port)

However the external display (U2414H) is stuck in **640 x 480 resolution** and can't go beyond that (grayed out in display setting)?

Answer (score 1):

After reading through this many pages long [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfacepro-surfver_surfpro7-surftop_install/monitor-stuck-on-displayport-with-640x480/fb4177e2-8c46-48b3-ae0e-168e9b86347b?page=1&rtAction=1618631960291), I found one of the reply (credit: **Ethan Chen**) is super useful and solved my problem.

To help more users in the same boat, I've rewritten the answer and added references as follows:

**Simply enabled DisplayPort 1.2 setting** on the Dell U2414H display, then Surface Pro 7 can recognize it and use the desired 1920 x 1080 resolution.

For those of you curious about how to enable that setting, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leNkQoJpz9M) told me how  (press 3rd button from the left to access the on-display menu). Also [this manual](https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/2d/14/2d143a64-ab3f-4923-8b27-6cf194cd97c8.pdf) (page 33) shows well how to use all the buttons.

Glad I don't need to try rolling back the Intel graphic driver or buying another USB-C display cable. Note that I did finish the two things mentioned in page 1 of that thread (clear cache and update firmware of the docking station). Had no luck but not sure if those eventually work in conjunction with the DisplayPort 1.2 setting.